# Real analysis, convexity problem

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

The course is an elementary course on Rudin so we don't have much material on convexity.

We have this problem concerning a convex subset, $C$, of $R^k$.

a) show that the closure $cl(C)$ is convex. DONE

Now b) below is the problem, I have no clue as where to even start!

b)
For some $v$ in $R^k$, assuming $v$ is not an interior point of $C$, show that there exists $a \neq 0$ such that:

$a^t v \leq a^t x$ for all $x \in C$

where $a^t$ is the transpose of a.

Basically I've come nowhere on this except that

$a^t v \leq a^t x= a^t (\lambda z + (1-\lambda)y)$ for  $\: 0 < \lambda \ <1$ and some points $z,y$ in $C$.

Any advice / solution is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

/I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Since $C$ is convex and $v$ is not in the interior of $C$, then there is a (hyper)plane which contains $v$ and does not contain any interior points of $C$. Look at the normal vectors of that plane.

Comment: This is extremely useful, I think my teacher hinted at something similar but I didn't quite understand what he/she meant. Thanks!

Edit: I don't think I have seen any previous material that states this. Do you know if I could've missed some theorem from previous classes? I didn't find this in Rudin.

Thanks again.

Comment: @inzie The [supporting hyperplane theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane_theorem) says that any point on the boundary has a hyperplane like this. As for a point $x$ _not_ on the boundary, it should be an immediate consequence of the theorem with a cleverly chosen $y$ on the boundary. Alternatively, by the hyperplane separation theorem with the compact set being the point $X$.

Comment: I really do appreciate all the help you give, I'm afraid I'm a bit thick when it comes to this though.

So far I've got that any point outside of $C$ or on the boundary  is in some hyperplane. But I don't see the connection between those and the $x \in C$. I don't think I can make this hyperplane into something more concrete in terms of what is given in the question, neither do I know how to make more concrete the normal vector, or any other projection into $C$.